# Set Dataset prefix mappings in Jena

Tags: rdf, jena

In Apache Jena, the namespace prefixes of a model can be set by using the method `setNsPrefixes()` of the model. Is there anything alike for instances of Dataset to set the prefixes before printing a dataset

Comment: Something like [that](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/core/DatasetPrefixStorage.html) ?

Comment: exactly, but after creating the DatasetPrefixStorage, when outputting the dataset, how do I consider the DatasetPrefixStorage because I don't find any method in Dataset which can consider the prefixes ?

Comment: Set them on the default model/graph of the dataset to affect writing.